# check a checkbox in a checkboxSelectionModel

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt-ext

so.. I have a checkboxSelectionGrid like the one in this link: http://gwt-ext.com/demo/#checkboxSelectionGrid

I want to select multiple post tex all with the same company.

 how do I do that?

Comment: Be descriptive about your question. What exactly do you want to achieve or the problem are you facing?

Comment: Source code is given with the example given in the link you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a little unclear as to whether you are wanting to preselect several with the same company name, or do something with them afterwards, but here is how I went about doing it.  Perhaps it will be of some use to someone.

***Note I'm using Reversible Fees, not Companies per the linked code, but the concept is the same.***
    private GridEx fees;

```
private GridEx<BeanModel> fees;
.
.
.
fees.getStore().add(feeItems); // this finishes adding all the items.
List<BeanModel> preselectedItems = new ArrayList<BeanModel>();
for (BeanModel feeItem : (fees.getStore() != null && fees.getStore().getModels() != null) ? fees.getStore().getModels() : Collections.<BeanModel>emptyList()) {
    if (feeItem.<ReversibleFee>getBean().isSelected()) {
        preselectedItems.add(feeItem);
    }
}
fees.getSelectionModel().select(preselectedItems, false);
```

If you are wanting to do something with the data every time a checkbox is checked, you can do it like so:

```
fees.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener<BeanModel>() {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<BeanModel> beanModelSelectionChangedEvent) {
        feeTotal.setValue(0);
        for (BeanModel anItem : fees.getStore().getModels()) {
            if (beanModelSelectionChangedEvent.getSelection().contains(anItem)) {
                anItem.<ReversibleFee>getBean().setSelected(true);
                feeTotal.setValue(feeTotal.nullSafeGetValue() + Math.abs(anItem.<ReversibleFee>getBean().getAmount()));
            } else {
                anItem.<ReversibleFee>getBean().setSelected(false);
            }

        }
    }
});
```

And finally, if you're wanting to do something with the data after submit, you can do it like so:

```
for (BeanModel beanModel : fees.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
    beanModel.<ReversibleFee>getBean().setAmount(788);    
}
```